# Are cumulus clouds analogous to airships flying downwards?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, action

First of all,  cumulus clouds are amazing.   Big puffy white clouds floating on the air.   Some of them produce updrafts of over 100 Km per hour.  Now, if an airship had its engine pointed towards the sky  and blasting up a 100 km per hour, it would be trying to fly towards the earth, wouldn't it? And it would be creating a suction below it too.  Could it be that this is happening in the cloud too?  Simple action and reaction?  Just because the cloud does not have a discrete envelope holding it all together, is not reason for it to disobey the law of action and equal and opposite reaction.  Anyway, this idea was by way of trying to underestand the biotic pump theory.  (I just could not understand its math).  Anyway,  I think the donut airship analogy is correct.   Do you? Here I am trying to explain it in a video.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPO8dWm_GIg

Answer (score 0):

Your question is especially unclear, and clouds are mostly air with a few microscopic water droplet (so not really "floating things").

Powerful vertical winds are in congestus and cumulonimbus rather than simple cumulus. When there are just updrafts, these are simply cause by Archimedes force because the parcels are lighter than the surrounding air. When getting stronger, a whole circulation like Benard-cells can establish. Maybe it is what you name "pump".

Beside this dry mechanics, there is all the effect of phase change of water, which is a powerful engine: as long as the parcel condensate (above dew point), it heats more and more, and get lighter and lighter compare to the environement, thus the "explosion" shape of convective cloud. ( Fortunately the hot ozone layer make a root, thus the anvil shape of Cb, otherwise all our water would have been pumped out).

Comment: Sorry,  I should have named it cumulonimbus.  These are the ones that produce powerful updrafts "within" the clouds due to the energy released by condensation within the cloud itself.  These are the ones where the cloud causes an "action" similar to  an engine and the updraft is the "jet of air" expelled from the cloud.  Newtonian physics,  I suggest that the cloud is moved slightly earthwards in "reaction"  to the expelled jet of air.  Of course some of the reaction will cause more swirl in the cloud but  a lowering of the cloud and a lowering of pressure under the cloud should also occur.

Comment: Please explain what similarity due you see with an engine. The updraft is not pushed, it is buoyant, which is quite a difference. Beside, in fluids your notion of "reaction" probably simply translates in 1: pressure balance 2: overall circulation (at different possible scale). Yes, updraft here means downdraft elsewhere. Depending of the scale and intensity it's right around one isolated draft, more diffusly around, or elsewhere as a large Benard-cell circulation.